# Remove Month Selection option from Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery UI datepicker to achieve custom range of Dates.

> I want to remove drop down of the month and want to add Static month name In from datepicker.

[image]

I can achieve it with sort of hacks, but Is there any other way that I can remove it directly from declaration.

Here is my code (Not full code but only initialization of From datepicker).

```
 var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
          from = $("#from")
            .datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1W",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                minDate: +7
          });
```

Comment: Did you try with `changeMonth: false`?
[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/xkx6jLtt/)

Comment: it works, wow, ..

Comment: Cool :), I have posted this as an answer. So that others can quickly find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `changeMonth` to false.

```
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $("#from")
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1W",
            changeMonth: false,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: +7
      });
```